# Creating a task scheduler in GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script

So I'm just getting back into scripting with GAS and I'm trying to make a scheduler/reminder system for tracking periodic maintenance that has to be done.

The idea is a form that fills info to a spreadsheet (easily done), and then iterate through the sheet and create events on a dedicated calendar for every 'job', with recurrence set to how often the job needs doing.  ie:  every 3 months, clean the drains.

I have this part of it working.  What I'm wondering is... is it possible to have a script call a function at a specified date and time?  Like instead of a calendar event that emails you a reminder about the event on the day of (or whenever), maybe call a function so that I can email them some details about the job (again, pulling from the sheet, which is simple enough) and maybe throw it at Pushbullet API to push to the user's phone/browser.  I've played with PB's api, and everything, the ONLY part of this that I don't have working is the scheduled future script firing.

If this isn't possible, would anyone be able to recommend an alternative?

Edit: For clarification, I'd be wanting to set up a one-time execution of a function on say ... June 14th.  In terms of recurrence, I can just have it set the next scheduled run during the execution.

Comment: Welcome! I think that you are looking for something like `cron` or possibly for GAS specifically, triggers- see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you need to use the Trigger!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it’s possible. Use time-driven triggers. For details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable